Shutting Down Last Exchange Server step 5b - How and where do I run Microsoft.Graph.Applications in PowerShell?
After completing all prior steps, which are all run in on-prem Exchange PowerShell, I have come to step 5b here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/manage-hybrid-exchange-recipients-with-management-tools#permanently-shutting-down-your-last-exchange-server
While I am pretty familiar with Windows PowerShell and Exchange Management Shell, I am not familiar with Microsoft Graph PowerShell.
After reading about it, it seems I need to run a command in PowerShell to Install a Microsoft Graph module for the next step I need to complete.
What I don't see in the instructions and can't find verification of, is where I install the module and what credentials do I use.
Is this something I can do from any domain-joined machine running PowerShell? Or does it need to be done on my server that runs Azure AD Connect? Or do I do this in Exchange Management Shell?
And what credentials do I use after installing to connect? The instructions say "run as a tenant admin" so that makes me think O365, but this is related to removing the on-prem Exchange server, so I don't see why I would run this in an O365 online PowerShell.

You can run it from any computer, domain-joined or not, as you'll be authenticating to Office 365 with your O365 GA credentials. You'll need to use your Office 365 Global Admin credentials when running this command.

Thank you, I was able to get Microsoft Graph Shell to run. However, unfortunately one of the commands Microsoft has in the guide is incorrect and returns an error stating that the command has an unexpected parameter, so I ended up having to use the older MSOnline Shell and commands to complete this step.

You first need to install the Microsoft Graph module before importing it, and how to install them is mentioned in this artical.Install-Module Microsoft Graph
You can import this module in Windows PowerShell or EMS.
Once installed, you'll need to authenticate with a tenant that has the role of Global Administrator.
